# What does the notation $P_{\overline{MM}}(t)$ mean in this context?

Tags: markov-process, random-walk, poisson-process

The notation $P_{\overline{MM}}(t)$ is used in part (iii) of the following question:

[image: notation]

I'm unsure of exactly what this notation represents. My guess would be that it represents the probability that a person who starts in the state $M$ at time $0$, is in the state $M$ at time $t$. Is this correct?

Comment: The states $\bar S$ might refer to the reduced process constructed in (ii) (which is the original process staying forever at $W$ or $D$ once it hits one of these states). Then indeed $p_{\bar M,\bar M}(t)$ is the probability that the reduced process starting at $\bar M$ is still at $\bar M$ at time $t$, that is, that the original process starting at $M$ stays at $M$ from time $0$ to time $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $P_{\overline{MM}}(t)$ denotes the probability that the process *remains* in the state $M$ for $t$ periods, without ever leaving that state, given that it starts in state $M$ at time $0$.